# How to display results with "0"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I am running to pull hours from a database.  I'm using 2 tables `Employee_TB` and `Payroll_Hours_TB`.  The query is working, however it's not displaying active employees with "0" hours. I would like the query to show those employees who are active `Employee_Tb.Active_Flag = 1` with hours, and 0 hours for the date range.

```
SELECT
   REPLACE(REPLACE(Employee_Tb.First_Name, '.', ''), ' ', '') AS FirstName,
   REPLACE(REPLACE(Employee_Tb.Last_Name, '.', ''), ' ', '') AS LastName,
   Employee_Tb.Home_Store_Id, Employee_Tb.Payroll_Id,
   SUM(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Hours_Worked) AS RegHours
FROM Employee_Tb
LEFT OUTER JOIN Payroll_Hours_Tb ON Employee_Tb.Employee_Id = Payroll_Hours_Tb.Employee_Id
WHERE (Payroll_Hours_Tb.Work_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
AND (Employee_Tb.Active_Flag = 1)
GROUP BY Employee_Tb.Payroll_Id, Employee_Tb.First_Name, Employee_Tb.Last_Name, Employee_Tb.Home_Store_Id
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the following condition from the `where` clause to the `on` clause:

```
(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Work_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
```

...like so:

```
-- simplified column list for demonstration
select
 e.Employee_Id
,coalesce(sum(h.Hours_Worked), 0) as RegHours
from Employee_Tb as e
    left join Payroll_Hours_Tb as h
    on e.Employee_Id = h.Employee_Id
    and h.Work_Date between @startdate and @enddate
where e.Active_Flag = 1
group by e.Employee_Id
```

Otherwise you're filtering the entire set *after* the join.

Comment: An alternative is to leave the condition in the `WHERE` clause, but handle the nulls on your own like so: `WHERE (Payroll_Hours_Tb.Work_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) OR Payroll_Hours_Tb.Work_Date is null`.  Some prefer to test on the key fields instead when the filtered field is nullable, so you could use `Payroll_Hours_Tb.Employee_Id is null` then, too.  Even though you're doing an `OUTER` join, when you specify a specific value you implicitly do an inner join.  Since `NULL BETWEEN '3/1/2013' and '3/13/2013'` is not `TRUE` (it's `NULL`) those fields get filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Is it showing null instead of 0?

Maybe you can try something like

`ISNULL(SUM(Payroll_Hours_Tb.Hours_Worked), 0) AS RegHours`